# How Do I make A steel Door Usable by All/Chosen Players?

Tags: minetest

I like the look of steel doors, but my other friends cannot open the door.  How do I make it so that they can open it?
I've heard of making keys, but I'm not sure how that works in Minetest, or if it is even practical.  Is there a command privilege perhaps?